# Dynamic type in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

```
const typeDef = `

  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
  }
  type Post { 
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String!
  }
  extend type Query {
    getDocuments(collection: String!): [User] || [Post]     // <<<<< Here!
  }   
`
```

Is it possible to define `getDocuments` type to `[User]` or `[Post]` both? 
I have several data collections (users, posts, payments etc...) and I want to define one getter `getDocuments` for fetching data for reducing duplicated code.

```
// like this

getDocuments(collection: 'User')
getDocuments(collection: 'Post')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/):

> GraphQL supports two abstract types: interfaces and unions.
>
> An Interface defines a list of fields; Object types that implement that interface are guaranteed to implement those fields. Whenever the type system claims it will return an interface, it will return a valid implementing type.
>
> A Union defines a list of possible types; similar to interfaces, whenever the type system claims a union will be returned, one of the possible types will be returned.

So you can do something like this:

```
union Document = User | Post

extend type Query {
  getDocuments(collection: String!): [Document]
}
```

If the types share one or more fields, you can use an Interface -- otherwise, you have to use a Union.

The field's type will be resolved at runtime based on the `resolveType` function you provide. See [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/) for additional details on how to provide the function to your type.

Lastly, when querying your field, you'll now need to use fragments to specify which fields to request depending on the type:

```
getDocuments {
  ... on User {
    id
    name
  }
  ... on Post {
    id
    title
  }
}
```